# How to create a minimalist HTML5 file from Markdown?

Tags: conversion, html, html5, markdown, pandoc

I have a simple Markdown file which I want to convert to a minimal HTML5 compliant file.

I tried:

- `pandoc -f markdown -t html5 .\description.md -o description.html` → this generates proper HTML content, but just for the Markdown content, there is no `<head>`, `<body>`, etc. (it is rendered correctly in a browser as it will assume many defaults, but I would like a complete HTML5 file)
- `pandoc --standalone -f markdown -t html5 .\description.md -o description.html` → the file is a proper HTML5 one, but some styling is added.

Is there a `pandoc --bare-do-not-add-anything-beyond-minimalist-html5-skeleton --standalone --f markdown -t html5 .\description.md -o description.html` version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using pandoc 2.11 or newer, as additional CSS was added in that version. You can get revert to the old behavior and get unstyled HTML by calling pandoc with `-M document-css=false`.